# WAMP/PHP error not in correct language

Tags: php, wamp

I am running wampserver 2.5, with php 5.5.12

When I run a php script, the errors' outputs are displayed using the french language. How can I change them so they are displayed using english ?

Oddly I tried to change the **intl.default_locale** to "en_US" in the *php.ini* file but no luck, nothing changed.
And I browsed the web enough to be confused and with no solutions.

Comment: @AbraCadaver I used to learn and document myself using english language, it is just a preference. Also, I guess there is more accurate answers when I copy/paste the output of a trouble i can't shoot in a search engine.

Comment: It was a joke because I do not know the answer :-(

Comment: @dan08 they are not MySQL errors as well, i saw that solution before.

Comment: dont know what to change, you can download the english wamp I guess :)